# помогите найти ошибку при выводе на страницу id="data_block" (не отображается)

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div id="date_block" class="date"></div>

    <script>
    function data_time {
        var d = new Data();

        var day = new Array("Воскресенье ", "Понедельник ", "Вторник ",
            "Среда ", "Четверг ", "Пятница ", "Суббота ");

        var month = new Array("января ", "февраля ", "марта ", "апреля ", "мая ", "июня ",
            "июля ", "августа ", "сентября ", "октября ", "ноября ", "декабря ");

        return day[d.getDay()] + " "
        d.getDate() + " " + month[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear() + " г. ";

    }
    document.getElementById(data_block).innerHTML = data_time();
    </script>
```

Comment: 1. `Data` → `Date`, 2. return прерывается вот тут `+ " "` Можно перенести пробельную строку на следующую строчку, оставив `+` в первой строчке, чтобы JS понимал, что выражение не закончилось. Но надежнее завернуть всё в скобки, `return ( ляляля )`

Comment: развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="date_block" class="date"></div>

<script>
  function data_time() {
    var day = new Array("Воскресенье ", "Понедельник ", "Вторник ",
      "Среда ", "Четверг ", "Пятница ", "Суббота ");
    var month = new Array("января ", "февраля ", "марта ", "апреля ", "мая ", "июня ",
      "июля ", "августа ", "сентября ", "октября ", "ноября ", "декабря ");

    var d = new Date();
    return day[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate() + " " +
      month[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear() + " г. ";
  }
  document.getElementById("date_block").innerHTML = data_time();
</script>
```

Comment: Игра "найди 10 отличий" ) Для незнающего может быть достаточно непросто...

Answer (score 1):

строки

```
function data_time {

var d = new Data();

return day[d.getDay()] + " "

document.getElementById(data_block).innerHTML = data_time();
```

поменяйте на :

```
function data_time() {

var d = new Date();

return day[d.getDay()] + " " +

document.getElementById("data_block").innerHTML = data_time();
```